# How to change Avatar in Swing?

Tags: java, image, swing

I am working on Java Swing, in the edit account form I want when I click a button it will go to the folder sections to find my pictures and load them.

Comment: [How to Use File Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)

Comment: Can you try to pinpoint the actual *problem* you have? Is it adding the button? Is it assigning an action to the button? Is it displaying a file chooser for the user to select an image? Is it loading the image? Displaying the image? Or perhaps something completely different?

Comment: oh , i need to show the file picker